# proplem facing while using dictionary

Tags: c#

i use dictionary in my simple code and do method taken an string as an key and search if it already exist in my dictionary if yes return valu  why my "search " function is not work ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary < string, string > DIC = new Dictionary < string, string > ();
        DIC.Add("NAME", "aly");
        DIC.Add("AGE", "TWENTY");
        DIC.Add("LOVE", "NO");
        DIC.Add("GENDER", "MALE AWII");
        DIC.Add("BROTHER", "NO");
        DIC.Add("SISTER", "HAVE TOw");
        DIC.Add("FACULTY", "CS");
        DIC.Add("country ", "us");

        string search(string wanted) {
            if (DIC.ContainsKey(wanted)) {
                string value = DIC[wanted];
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't even successfully compiled you can not declare a method inside a method. I strongly recommend you to go thorough some C# tutorial before starting development.

Comment: thank you for your comment and advice i will take it carefully  ....but can i have correct code for it

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, it is not possible to nest a method within a method in `C#`. You need to move the search method to the class level.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> DIC = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
        DIC.Add("NAME", "aly");
        DIC.Add("AGE", "TWENTY");
        DIC.Add("LOVE", "NO");
        DIC.Add("GENDER", "MALE AWII");
        DIC.Add("BROTHER", "NO");
        DIC.Add("SISTER", "HAVE TOw");
        DIC.Add("FACULTY", "CS");
        DIC.Add("country ", "us");

        string value = this.Search(DIC, "country");

        // Do something with value
    }

    private static string Search(Dictionary<string, string> DIC, string wanted) 
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        if (DIC.ContainsKey(wanted)) 
        {
            value = DIC[wanted];
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```